# Some SBT dependencies are ignored

Tags: eclipse, scala, dependencies, sbt, scalatra

I use SBT to include dependencies in my project, but I couldn't find the reason why some dependencies are ignored randomly. Even if they exist in `.ivy2/cache` directory, I tried to delete the content of it and retry but I still have the same problem.

The version of my SBT is `0.13.15` here is an example:

```
import org.scalatra.sbt._
import org.scalatra.sbt.PluginKeys._
import ScalateKeys._

val ScalatraVersion = "2.4.1"

ScalatraPlugin.scalatraSettings

scalateSettings

organization := "com.*****"

name := "****"

version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

val sparkVersion = "1.6.0"

resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeReleases

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-json" % ScalatraVersion,
  "org.json4s"   %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.11",
  "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % ScalatraVersion,
  "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-scalate" % ScalatraVersion,
  "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-specs2" % ScalatraVersion % "test",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.5" % "runtime",
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "9.2.15.v20160210" % "container",
  "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.1.0" % "provided"
)
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.2.14"

scalateTemplateConfig in Compile := {
  val base = (sourceDirectory in Compile).value
  Seq(
    TemplateConfig(
      base / "webapp" / "WEB-INF" / "templates",
      Seq.empty,  /* default imports should be added here */
      Seq(
        Binding("context", "_root_.org.scalatra.scalate.ScalatraRenderContext", importMembers = true, isImplicit = true)
      ),  /* add extra bindings here */
      Some("templates")
    )
  )
}

enablePlugins(JettyPlugin)
```

In my example, sometimes the `scalatra json`is ignored and when I retried to create a new project the `spark`dependencies was ignored

Comment: Any reason why you're using an sbt version that's almost 3 years old?

Comment: Sorry it's 0.13.15

Comment: Ok. But Scala is 2.10.5, right?

Comment: How does the problem manifest itself? Do you have a compilation error when running `scalac`? Does you IDE report that it cannot find a certain package? Is the library missing from a fat JAR you are building? Something else?

Comment: Yes all the informations in the build.sbt file are correct @mfirry

Comment: Yes I don't find the library in the referenced libraries into my eclipse project tree, so the dependencies are not imported but the project compiles. My IDE and SBT don't throw any error

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution of my issues, my project had to be converted to eclipse project through SBT with `sbt eclipse` command.
 Initially the Scalatra project was created via SBT with this command: 
`sbt new scalatra/scalatra-sbt.g8`

The trick is to eclipsify the project before beginning to import dependencies.